# Rails: select random objects daily?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example, I want to do a `daily pick`, so I need to select some random objects.

So I do this `@posts = Posts.all.shuffle`.

However, I don't want it changes every time the user enter the page. Rather, I just need it to change every day.(i.e `daily pick`)

How can I do it?

Comment: You probably need to store the latest pick somewhere along with the time it was picked.

Comment: Please run cron job once a day to pick random objects and store picked ids to database.

Comment: You can use **Whenever Gem** to schedule the cron.

Comment: here is the link https://github.com/javan/whenever

Comment: @AmitSharma It's now a free web app on heroku, which does not support `whenever`...

Comment: There is an scheduler add on available on heroku in which u can schedule rake task

Comment: @AmitSharma I mean it's not a free add on, right?

Comment: i think its a free add on please confirm once on heroku

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to do this, which is best depends on your particular application.  Not knowing anything about your application I would probably do the following:

Configure Rails caching to use something like memcached or redis or anything that supports key based expiration.

In app/models/post.rb:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.daily_picks
    Rails.cache.fetch('post_daily_picks', expires_in: 1.day) do
      self.all.shuffle.limit(5)
    end
  end
end
```

Now you can simply use `Post.daily_picks` elsewhere in your code and you'll have access to those 5 randomly selected picks.  The key will expire in 1 day at which point it will be regenerated.

Some other thoughts:

`self.all.shuffle.limit(5)` could get really expensive DB-query wise if you have any decent number of posts.  You may want to consider doing something fancy with the total number of posts, random numbers, and SQL's offset.  It would mean 5 queries instead of one, but you wouldn't be returning all the posts only to select 5.  Something like this for example:

`5.times.map { self.offset(rand(self.count)).first }`

If you can't setup memcached/redis and have to use file based caching that's okay.  You just need to add a cron job that removes the cache file once a day.

Keep in mind that the above will fetch 5 posts and cache them for a day.  If those posts change throughout the day the cached version won't reflect that (ie. old post titles will be used).  You may want to do this instead.  Which would simply cache the 5 post ids, and then fetch them every time.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.daily_picks
    daily_pick_ids = Rails.cache.fetch('post_daily_picks', expires_in: 1.day) do
      self.pluck(:id).shuffle.limit(5)
    end
    self.where(ids: daily_pick_ids)
  end
end
```

And lastly, consider the [thundering hurd problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundering_herd_problem).  Let's say you have thousands of active requests all using daily picks.  And the cache expires.  And 1,000 people refresh that page.  Due to race conditions a good number are going to execute that SQL.  I have a feeling it's not a big deal for this, but it's worth keeping in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Philip's idea is great but as he mentioned about the thundering hurd problem I was wondering about some other approach. This is what came into my mind:

```
time = Time.now
@posts = Posts.all
```

and to pick one post for a day you can use:

```
Posts.find(time.yday%@posts.size)
```

You should be able to develop it to pick more.

Comment: @Philip: please tell me what do you think about it. I have almost no experience in Ruby/Rails and I'm very curious about your opinion.

Comment: ahh.. and of course it's not very precise as if you create some new posts by that day it'll change its results but I believe it should be fine depends on your needs. You can put one more constrain to `.size` only posts older than one day to fix that.

Comment: You certainly could do something like that as long as you understand it isn't technically random.  It may well be random enough.  Also, you don't want to use just `find` in case you have a gap in the ID sequence it may not find that result.  You'd want to use offset/first instead.

Comment: Good point about the gaps. The main idea was to map the day to post.